# Handling iOS Audio Streams

Tags: ios, ios7, core-audio

Is it possible to handle the audio output of other iOS apps from a single app?

This would be muting, as well as directing where the audio is going (Bluetooth, speaker, headphone,etc.).

I am very unfamiliar with iOS programming, thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [AudioBus](http://audiob.us) and [Inter-App Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) in iOS 7

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into Inter-App Audio.  I think that would be a good start.  As a base, I'm trying to see if it's possible for one app, to control where the audio of other apps will go.  Maybe I phrased my question ambiguously.